# Why eth0 can't access to loopback interface when using curl 127.0.0.1 --interface eth0

Tags: linux, networking, routing, curl, tcp-ip

Here is how to reproduce this problem:

1. Start a listen service on port 80: `nc -l 80 -k`
2. Access this service using curl: `curl 127.0.0.1 --interface eth0`
3. Capture the packet using tcpdump both on `eth0` and `lo`: `tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 -nn -v`, `tcpdump -i lo port 80 -nn -v`

The `tcpdump` output shows that the `SYN` packet was sent from `eth0` and didn't get any reply, the tcp client just retransmit `SYN` until reach the retransmission limits.

However when I changed the destination ip to `192.168.16.4` (also a local ip which is bounded to eth0), accessing succeeded, and the tcpdump output shows that the `SYN` packet was sent from `lo`.

Here is the `ifconfig` output:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.16.4  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::f820:20ff:fe16:588c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:20:20:16:58:8c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16248748  bytes 2161348902 (2.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15203841  bytes 4648786129 (4.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4832071  bytes 2872871764 (2.6 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4832071  bytes 2872871764 (2.6 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And the route table content:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.16.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 192.168.16.2    255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
192.168.16.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     100    0        0 eth0

$ ip route show table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.16.0 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.4 
local 192.168.16.4 dev eth0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.16.4 
broadcast 192.168.31.255 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.4
```

I use `strace` to record the systemcall log when `curl`, it shows that `--interface eth0` option means: `setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth0\0", 5)`

I have seen the discussion in https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/198 (the `ping -I` does in the same way) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036667/route-between-network-interfaces-ubuntu

I'm wondering:

1. Why `curl 127.0.0.1 --interface eth0` can't access the service, what happened to the `SYN` packet and when it's dropped?
2. Why `curl 192.168.16.4 --interface eth0` is using `lo` interface to communicate but `curl 127.0.0.1 --interface eth0` using `eth0`
3. What I should do if I want `curl 127.0.0.1 --interface eth0` can work.

---

### **Update:**

The Linux Kernel version I'm using is `4.18.0`. And for `curl 192.168.16.4 --interface eth0`, the `tcpdump -i lo` output is:

```
$ tcpdump -i lo port 80 -nn
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:15:38.915880 IP 192.168.16.4.40850 > 192.168.16.4.80: Flags [S], seq 1020241664, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2673572844 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:15:38.915891 IP 192.168.16.4.80 > 192.168.16.4.40850: Flags [S.], seq 3808229193, ack 1020241665, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2673572844 ecr 2673572844,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:15:38.915900 IP 192.168.16.4.40850 > 192.168.16.4.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 2673572844 ecr 2673572844], length 0
09:15:38.915928 IP 192.168.16.4.40850 > 192.168.16.4.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:77, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 2673572844 ecr 2673572844], length 76: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
09:15:38.915931 IP 192.168.16.4.80 > 192.168.16.4.40850: Flags [.], ack 77, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 2673572844 ecr 2673572844], length 0
```

Comment: I don't know how to answer this other than "127.0.0.1 is only bound to `lo` and no other interface". That's simply what the loopback interface is designed to do.

Comment: @Panki So you mean it's impossible for `lo` to communicate with `eth0`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks very much like an XY-problem, but:

There are two interfaces on your system:

- `eth0`, with an IP address of 192.168.16.4
- `lo`, with an IP address of 127.0.0.1

Of course, all directly connected IP addresses to that interface will be accessible via that interface. For `eth0` that would be anything in 192.168.16.0/20 and for `lo`, anything in 127.0.0.1.

For anything not in the directly coupled range, the data will first be sent to the gateway, which will then route it further on to the destination. So far, so good.

However, 127.0.0.0/8 is reserved for the loopback network. The router will not route that further. So even if you send it to the gateway, it will not be routed further-on.

Even if the router would route it further, there is no access to your `lo` interface. For `eth0`, the router has access via that cable that you plugged in. There is no such access to your `lo` interface; it is accessible only on your local system.

So, to your questions:

- Why `curl 127.0.0.1 --interface eth0` can't access the service, what happened to the SYN packet and when it's dropped?

Where it is dropped depends a bit on your OS. But it will not get any further than the gateway.

- Why `curl 192.168.16.4 --interface eth0` is using `lo` interface to communicate but `curl 127.0.0.1 --interface eth0` using `eth0`

This simply does not happen. `curl 192.168.16.4 --interface eth0` does not use `lo`.

- What I should do if I want `curl 127.0.0.1 --interface eth0` can work.

Kernel patches, if you have `systemd` running, patches there too. `curl` should be OK. You will also need a custom software on the router. You will need routing enabled on your system (with the aforementioned kernel patches applied of course and a modified version of `zebra`). My advice: don't even think about it. Seriously re-evaluate why you would even want to try this.

As addition, as elaborate response to

> But the curl 192.168.16.4 --interface eth0 did use lo interface

What you might see on device with `systemd` is (using `curl dullaart.website`):

```
07:41:06.008577 IP localhost.domain > localhost.45840: 6127 1/0/0 PTR localhost. (64)
07:41:12.433744 IP localhost.52411 > localhost.domain: 39930+ A? dullaart.website. (34)
07:41:12.433795 IP localhost.52411 > localhost.domain: 49165+ AAAA? dullaart.website. (34)
07:41:12.550329 IP localhost.domain > localhost.52411: 39930 1/0/0 A 212.1.212.17 (50)
07:41:12.582833 IP localhost.domain > localhost.52411: 49165 0/0/0 (34)
```

This is name resolving that is done on the server that is specified in `/etc/resolve.conf`, which is

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

That is on the loopback network.

Some systems (but not all) may use `lo` as a short-cut if you go to your own system (as you did in the `curl` output in your question). This can be done, because the kernel knows that the same system is behind both interfaces. So `curl` may use `lo` if, and only if, your target is your own system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah this requirement is strange, I just want to understand how these stuffs work.  But the `curl 192.168.16.4 --interface eth0` did use `lo` interface, I was using `tcpdump -i lo` to watch, you can also try.